# How to Make gVim Transparent

Tags: gvim, colorscheme

I am using Vim on Arch Linux. One thing I like to do is using my transparent terminal I can be editing a latex file and have it automatically compiling and showing behind what I am writing. Is there a way to get the same transparency in gVim? What option should I add to my `.gvimrc`?

In order to ensure proper transparency in terminal all I set is:

```
let g:solarized_termtrans=1
```

Comment: I don't think gVim supports transparency. Only MacVim does. There's a patch mentioned in the TODO list which supposedly adds transparency only for gVim in Windows. You might have to use tricks like the one in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Per_Application_Transparency (which mentions gVim).